# php register globals on/off through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, register-globals

I have 2 scritpts on 2 different folders.
One on them need the register globals to On and the other to Off.

Is it possible to enable regsiter globals on one folder and disable it on another one ?
(maybe with a .htaccess ?)

regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if your apache instance allows you to override flags through `.htaccess` you can put the following in your file:

```
php_flag register_globals off
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a login script that works like this:
User type username and pass, if ok then save user data in a session and redirect to restrict area. I hosted my site in bluehost.com and it works perfectly.
So for some reasons I've decided to change to hostgator.com and session stopped save data from user. All I have to do is add to `php.ini` a line to disable `register_globals`

```
register_globals=Off
```